# Tomcat verbiage: stop vs kill

Tags: java, tomcat, process

What is the difference (in Tomcat terminology) between "*stopping*" Tomcat, and just killing the process?

If Tomcat has a pid of, say, 500, then what is the difference between:

> kill -9 500

And

> service tomcat stop

?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same thing as with every other process on the planet? You can't handle a `SIGKILL` in a program.

Comment: Thank you Brian but this answer does not help me. I am asking what the difference is between running these two commands from the terminal. Thanks again!

Comment: They do two completely different things. One sends a `SIGKILL` and one sends a `SIGTERM`

Comment: More info on SIGTERM vs SIGKILL [here](http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/). It depends on the application how much practical difference it makes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kill = bam! it's dead.

Stop = allow it to end gracefully. Any running applications can run any code they have for this occurance. The server instance iself will gracefully release resources.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question but the following is a simple shell script that I use on a day to day basis to kill my tomcat processes:

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

https://gist.github.com/nrshrivatsan/1d2ea4fcdcb9d1857076

**Part 1**

```
ps -ef | grep  tomcat  => Get all processes with tomcat grep
```

**Part 2**

Once we have process details, we pipe it into the part 2 of the script

```
awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 => Get the second column [Process id] and kill them with -9 option
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Shrivats.